# Pandas: groupby and shift not doing quite what I need

Tags: python, pandas

Here is a small dataset:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'KEY' : [100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 102, 102],
                   'RPTDATE' : ['2002-10-23', '2002-10-23', '2002-10-30', '2002-10-30', '2002-11-6', '2002-11-6', \
                                '2005-12-7', '2005-12-7','2005-12-7','2005-12-21','2005-12-21','2005-12-21','2005-12-21','2005-12-21', \
                                '2005-12-21','2006-1-4','2006-1-4','2006-1-4', '2015-7-8', '2015-7-8'],
                    'ENDDEPTH' : [3248, 3248, 10998, 10998, 12545, 12545, 12836, 12836, 12836, 18744, 18744, 18744, \
                                18744, 18744, 18744, 20255, 20255, 20255, 6250, 6250],
                    'CODE' : ['GR', 'RES', 'GR', 'RES', 'GR', 'RES', 'GR', 'RES', 'PWD', 'GR', 'RES', 'PWD', 'DEN', 'NEUT', \
                              'SON', 'GR', 'RES', 'PWD', 'APWD', 'ARC']})
```

[image: Dataframe example]

I originally needed to create a new column called STDEPTH and populate it by using the ENDDEPTH of the line above when the KEY was the same. If the KEY was not the same, the STARTDATE would be 0. With the help of someone here on SO, I created this script:

```
 df['STDEPTH'] = df.groupby(['KEY','CODE'])['ENDDEPTH'].shift(fill_value=0)
```

This generates the dateframe above, which is almost what I need; however the 3 highlighted 0s in lines 12-14 need to be the same as lines 9-11. If I remove 'CODE' from the script, I get this:

[image: Dataframe without CODE]

If I change 'CODE' to 'RPTDATE' the STDEPTH populates with a 0 whenever the date changes.

What do I need to do so that the STDEPTH consistently follows the ENDDEPTH of the previous row no matter what the CODE is?

Thanks!

Comment: Code you post what you want in the final dataframe? To me, it seems the last one (image) you posted does what you need: `STDEPTH` for new `KEY`s start with `0` and otherwise the `STDEPTH` is the previous `ENDDEPTH`; and ignores changes in `CODE`. For the three rows with highlighted 0's in the first image, did you want them to be `12836` or `18744`?

Comment: In the image with the highlighted 0s, they need to be 12836, just like the row above them. Basically, all STDEPHTs with a RPTDATE of 2015-12-21 need to be 12836.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with your original `df` as provided and doing the same first step. Then create a dataframe of unique "KEY, RPTDATE, STDEPTH, ENDDEPTH" values where STDEPTH is not 0 and use that to fill values where STDEPTH is 0:

```py
import numpy as np  # needed later

df.insert(2, 'STDEPTH', 0)  # place the new column in a useful place
# the first step as you originally did:
df['STDEPTH'] = df.groupby(['KEY','CODE'])['ENDDEPTH'].shift(fill_value=0)

# create the dataframe which has the needed UNIQUE values
match_start = df[df['STDEPTH'] != 0][['KEY', 'RPTDATE', 'STDEPTH', 'ENDDEPTH']].drop_duplicates()
```

`match_start` is:

```
    KEY     RPTDATE  STDEPTH  ENDDEPTH
2   100  2002-10-30     3248     10998
4   100   2002-11-6    10998     12545
9   101  2005-12-21    12836     18744
15  101    2006-1-4    18744     20255
```

[Join](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) with the previous unique non-missing values:

```py
df = df.join(match_start.set_index(['KEY', 'RPTDATE', 'ENDDEPTH']),
             on=['KEY', 'RPTDATE', 'ENDDEPTH'],
             rsuffix='_match')
```

`df[7:16]` looks like:

```
    KEY     RPTDATE  STDEPTH  ENDDEPTH  CODE  STDEPTH_match
7   101   2005-12-7        0     12836   RES            NaN
8   101   2005-12-7        0     12836   PWD            NaN
9   101  2005-12-21    12836     18744    GR        12836.0
10  101  2005-12-21    12836     18744   RES        12836.0
11  101  2005-12-21    12836     18744   PWD        12836.0
12  101  2005-12-21        0     18744   DEN        12836.0
13  101  2005-12-21        0     18744  NEUT        12836.0
14  101  2005-12-21        0     18744   SON        12836.0
15  101    2006-1-4    18744     20255    GR        18744.0
```

Assign the "right" values to STDEPTH, using [`np.where()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```py
df['STDEPTH'] = np.where((df['STDEPTH'] == 0) & (df['STDEPTH_match'].notna()),
                         df['STDEPTH_match'],  # value if True
                         df['STDEPTH']         # value if False
                        ).astype(int)  # convert to int's

# remove the extra column
df.drop('STDEPTH_match', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Result `df`:

```
    KEY     RPTDATE  STDEPTH  ENDDEPTH  CODE
0   100  2002-10-23        0      3248    GR
1   100  2002-10-23        0      3248   RES
2   100  2002-10-30     3248     10998    GR
3   100  2002-10-30     3248     10998   RES
4   100   2002-11-6    10998     12545    GR
5   100   2002-11-6    10998     12545   RES
6   101   2005-12-7        0     12836    GR
7   101   2005-12-7        0     12836   RES
8   101   2005-12-7        0     12836   PWD
9   101  2005-12-21    12836     18744    GR
10  101  2005-12-21    12836     18744   RES
11  101  2005-12-21    12836     18744   PWD
12  101  2005-12-21    12836     18744   DEN
13  101  2005-12-21    12836     18744  NEUT
14  101  2005-12-21    12836     18744   SON
15  101    2006-1-4    18744     20255    GR
16  101    2006-1-4    18744     20255   RES
17  101    2006-1-4    18744     20255   PWD
18  102    2015-7-8        0      6250  APWD
19  102    2015-7-8        0      6250   ARC
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. It does exactly what I need.